# How do I populate US states in a java SWT combo box?

Tags: java, swt

So I am doing a java SWT application, and I am wondering whether I can populate countries or US states without manually keying in those values into a java SWT combo box?

Must I link it to a web service?

Any suggestions and thoughts might be useful. Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a pretty sexy application!

Comment: What do you mean by populate? What values do you want to "key in"? What are you talking about?

Comment: It is fine, I just hard-coded 50 states in a String array.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be to create an `enum` of all the states in the United States. I'm sure there are lists online you *could* use, but linking to a web service is risky because the person using your application might not have internet or the server could go down and then your application would no longer work.